# Who wrote the School of Rock blackboard?

Tags: plot-explanation, soundtrack, school-of-rock

Can someone give more information about School of Rock blackboard? Who wrote it? Is there any information pertaining to this?

[image]

Comment: one of the students definitely or may be its dewey himself. you might want to rephrase the question? or it might be closed

Comment: probably something like a backdrop to the contents of the blackboard seems a valid question to me

Comment: @francesco, I think a better question is the simplest question: "what exactly does the blackboard say?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This diagram is based on [Edward Tufte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte)'s third book called [Visual Explanations: Images and Quantities, Evidence and Narrative](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961392126)

It is the first visually diagam how rock music has evolved over the last 50 years.
[image]
<sub>[Original link for image](https://web.archive.org/web/20170223003008/http://fakeplasticrock.com/wp-content/uploads/genealogy-of-pop-and-rock-music.png)</sub>

This poster is $45 for an [“archival paper”](http://www.historyshots.com/rockmusic/) print, but it only goes up to 1978.

The contents of [the School of Rock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0332379/) blackboard were transcribed like this;

[image]

There’s also an interesting site [The Family Tree of Rock and Roll](http://www.rockfamilytree.com/).

Comment: I have wondered exactly what the chalkboard read for  years! Thanks for this!

Comment: I like how this redrawing makes it look like KC & the Sunshine Band might be a rap group. (Or that Dr. Dre is disco.)

Comment: It's a pity there is no commons family tree of rock otherwise we could all learn so much from this :(

Answer (score 2):

Jack Black explained on the Watt from Pedro podcast that the director, cast and crew filled it out.  He wanted to make sure the interviewer, Mike Watt, knew that he had added in Watt's band, the Minutemen, because he is a huge fan.

Comment: Do you have a link to the mentioned podcast?